# in-app purchase with different binaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app where the user can make in-app purchases. The problem is that the binaries for iPad and iPhone are going to be different. Is there any way to share the in-app purchases between both apps so that the user doesn't have to pay twice for the same thing?

I think there is no way to do this, but maybe there is any suggestion.

My best regards,
Antonio.

Comment: What type of products are you selling? Subscriptions, consumables or non-consumables?

Comment: Hi nduplessis. Non-consumable products.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot share in-app-purchases between different apps. The solution is to create a universal app which serves both hardware platforms. 
It may be confusing in the beginning, but you do not have to maintain two codebases on the long run. So make your code conditional, like ...

- check if you are on an iPad

```
    BOOL isIPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
```

- load your .xib files conditonally

```
    NSString *conditionalXibName = isIPad ? @"MyXibFileName-iPadVersion" : @"MyXibFileName-iPhoneVersion";
    UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:conditionalXibName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Hi crosscode. Thank you for your reply. I will try to do it but may be I have problems with the size. Thank you!

Comment: In order to help with sizing, ensure you set the correct autoResizingMask on your views...

Comment: Hi adam. The problem is with the size from the whole app, not the views.